# How to use Mongoose to insert data from a list?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a long list of data which i need to insert in a cleanest way possible.

```
AB!@17078281
ba#@483031891
CA*!5133223312
...
da!@536270674233.4
```

Theoretical way:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c59bbb63f19612be376ef01"),
    "AB!@17078281" : "AB!@17078281",
    "ba#@483031891" : "ba#@483031891",
    "CA*!5133223312" : "CA*!5133223312",
     ... 
    "da!@536270674233.4" : "da!@536270674233.4"

}
```

The issue is i have over 10k and i'd assume this is not the best way do it. I need to read them later on in my program too but i do not know how to 'insert' them or read them directly instead of going through the name in node.js.
Another issue is with the schema.

```
var listOfUIDS = mongoose.Schema({
     ????? //i am not going to put 10k+ declarations here 
    });
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you have to use mongodb ? If your data is like this use a SQL db, insert your data row by row in a table and give them ID as primary key. Will be much more faster than traversing a JSON object.

Comment: because i saw a tutorial on node.js and this is the only database which seemed to work for me... Although thanks i will try :D

Comment: Which one would be the best for this instance?

Comment: Can't you just put the list as one of the value in the collection or you want all these items in the list as key-value pair?

Comment: a key-value pair